# CURL posting hangs with identical headers and content as on web application

Tags: curl, post

I need invoke a command of a web application using the shell script. I've saved request using web console looking like below:

```
  "request": {
          "bodySize": 233,
          "method": "POST",
          "url": "http://192.168.1.111/upload.cgi",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "192.168.1.111"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "en-US,en;q=0.5"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-Requested-With",
              "value": "XMLHttpRequest"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------34519157103616466683955440139"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "221"
            },
            {
              "name": "Origin",
              "value": "http://192.168.1.111"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "http://192.168.1.111/commissioning/index.html"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "queryString": [],
          "headersSize": 481,
          "postData": {
            "mimeType": "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------34519157103616466683955440139",
            "params": [],
            "text": "-----------------------------34519157103616466683955440139\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"test2.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\ntest test test\r\n-----------------------------34519157103616466683955440139--\r\n"
          }
        },
```

Therefore, I've constructed CURL command:

```
curl --data-binary "@tmp.bin" 'http://192.168.1.111/upload.cgi' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Host: 192.168.1.111' -H '
Origin: http://192.168.1.111' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------34519157103616466683955440139' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9' -H 'X-Requested-W
ith: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer: http://192.168.1.111/commissioning/index.html' -v
```

And corresponding payload file:

```
-----------------------------34519157103616466683955440139
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="test2.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

test test test
-----------------------------34519157103616466683955440139--
```

It outputs header files which looks identical as in web browser request, and it stops - cursor blinking so I have to Ctrl-C to stop it. That's interesting that it behaves in exactly the same way regardless which file I indicate after --data-binary. I suspect that the content file may be misformed somehow, but I do not have a clue after many trials - putting parentheses, putting /r/n instead of newlines, etc.